How best to fill cutouts in concrete just outside of garage door
Just outside the door I'm installing, on either side, there are two cutouts like this. No idea why they are there.

I happened to mention it to a friend and he suggested something called Vulkem. I'd never heard of that but a Google search said it's some kind of sealant. I was also thinking about mixing up some Quikrete and just filling them in. Thoughts?

Off hand, a piece of trim was there at some point.  Filling it should depend on local weather conditions.  Desert or rain requires different sealing.

I live in Northern California so hot summers, cold, but not freezing, winters. We have gotten a lot of rain the last couple years. Do you think running trim all the way down will keep water from filling those gaps?

Thoughts? is a vague question ... any answer would be correct, so such a question is off topic here ... what is your real question?

Sorry. New to all this. I guess my specific question would be what's the best way to fill the cutouts in the concrete to possibly prevent water from running into the garage.

I'd fill it full depth (or at least a couple inches deep on sand) with a vinyl or latex-fortified patch product. The additive makes it bond better to the existing concrete and keeps it a bit pliable to prevent cracking.
Plain concrete is likely to crack up before long. Hydraulic cement may be more expensive, but would also work. Caulks would not match particularly well.

Personally, I'd fill it up to about 1/2" from the surface with sand or small gravel, and top with a self-leveling concrete sealant, like Sikaflex Crack Flex (there are other similar products).
Might be worth running some sealant all along the joint where the driveway meets the vertical surfaces.

Hydraulic cement is great for applications like this. You can buy it wet, apply with a putty knife and smooth real nice with a scotch pad as it dries.

I ended up using the hydraulic cement. Worked great! Thank you everyone!
